# std::funtion C++11

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

Нужно загружать функции OpenGL и вызывать их через указатель. Все бы ничего, но преподаватель заставил вместо указателя использовать std::function. С ним возникает проблема, вроде все запускается, но работает не корректно.

Минимальный пример:

```
    typedef void ( * PGLCLEARCOLORPROC )  (GLclampf red, GLclampf green, GLclampf blue, GLclampf alpha);

    std::function <void (GLclampf, GLclampf, GLclampf, GLclampf)> _glClearColor = NULL;

    void glClearColor ( GLclampf red, GLclampf green, GLclampf blue, GLclampf alpha)
    {
        if(_glClearColor == NULL)
            _glClearColor = ( PGLCLEARCOLORPROC ) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress( "glClearColor" );
        else
            _glClearColor (  red,  green,  blue,  alpha );
    }
```

mygl.h

```
#ifndef LAB1_HL_S11_V1_MYGL_H
#define LAB1_HL_S11_V1_MYGL_H

typedef unsigned int GLenum;
typedef unsigned int GLbitfield;
typedef unsigned int GLuint;
typedef int GLint;
typedef int GLsizei;
typedef unsigned char GLboolean;
typedef signed char GLbyte;
typedef short GLshort;
typedef unsigned char GLubyte;
typedef unsigned short GLushort;
typedef unsigned long GLulong;
typedef float GLfloat;
typedef float GLclampf;
typedef double GLdouble;
typedef double GLclampd;
typedef void GLvoid;
typedef char GLchar;

#define GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT 0x00004000

typedef void ( * PGLCLEARPROC )  (GLbitfield mask);
typedef void ( * PGLCLEARCOLORPROC )  (GLclampf red, GLclampf green, GLclampf blue, GLclampf alpha);

bool mygl_Init(const char *);
void mygl_Quit();

void glClear(GLbitfield mask);
void glClearColor(GLclampf red, GLclampf green, GLclampf blue, GLclampf alpha);

#endif //LAB1_HL_S11_V1_MYGL_H
```

mygl.cpp

```
#include "mygl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

std::function <void (GLclampf, GLclampf, GLclampf, GLclampf)> _glClearColor = NULL;
std::function <void (GLbitfield)> _glClear = NULL;

bool mygl_Init(const char *str)
{
    if (SDL_GL_LoadLibrary(str) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error in load library" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void mygl_Quit()
{
    SDL_GL_UnloadLibrary();
}

void glClearColor ( GLclampf red, GLclampf green, GLclampf blue, GLclampf alpha)
{
    if(_glClearColor == NULL)
        _glClearColor = ( PGLCLEARCOLORPROC ) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress( "glClearColor" );
    else
        _glClearColor (  red,  green,  blue,  alpha );
}

void glClear (GLbitfield mask)
{
    if( _glClear == NULL) {
        _glClear = (PGLCLEARPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glClearColor");
        std::cout << "glClear is NULL" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        _glClear (mask);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mygl.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main()
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Event e;
    bool quit = false;

    if (!mygl_Init(NULL))
        return 0;


    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Lab 1", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if(!window)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error in create window" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    if(!glContext)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error in create gl context" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while( e.type != SDL_QUIT && !quit)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
        {
            glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
            if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_q && SDL_GetModState() & KMOD_CTRL)
                quit = true;
        }
    }


    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    mygl_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Результат работы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите минимально проверяемый пример проблемы. Никто не будет разбираться в ваших простынях кода.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow добавил

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.

Пока из возможных ошибок вижу неправильное получение указателя на функцию `glClear`.
Вы зачем-то делаете:

```cpp
_glClear = (PGLCLEARPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glClearColor");
```

а должно быть скорее всего:

```
_glClear = (PGLCLEARPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glClear");
```

Также лучше отказаться от проверки на `NULL`(странно, почему не `nullptr`?).

Есть хороший оператор проверки валидности:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool